# Universal links iOS : open store link if app NOT installed

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Have successfully integrated the universal link into app , please guide how can I redirect to store link if app is not installed , please suggest the correct approach to do it thanks

Comment: I think you can't do this because you can't check that an app is already installed on ios. If your app is not installed deep link will open your app's website.

Comment: which application do you want to check? your own?

Comment: If user clicks on link in SMS , it redirects user to app if  app is installed else to store link

Answer (score -1):

please try this:

```
    guard let link = URL(string: sahareUrl) else { return }
    let dynamicLinksDomain = "name.page.link"
    let linkBuilder = FIRDynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: dynamicLinksDomain)
    linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters = FIRDynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
    linkBuilder.options = FIRDynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
    linkBuilder.options?.pathLength = .short
    linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters?.imageURL = URL(string: imagename)
    linkBuilder.iOSParameters = FIRDynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "yourBundleId")
    linkBuilder.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "storeId"
    linkBuilder.iOSParameters?.iPadBundleID = "yourBundleId"
    linkBuilder.androidParameters = FIRDynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "packageNameOfAndroid")
    linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = title
    linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = description

    guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder.url else { return }
    print(longDynamicLink)

    FIRDynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(longDynamicLink, options: nil) { url, warnings, error in
        self.runOnUIThread {

            if url != nil{
                self.shareAds(item: [url!])
            }else{
                NVActivityIndicatorHelper.hideIndicatorInView()
            }
        }
    }
```

It may helps you.Thank you